# Getting 503 Service Unavailable when trying to generate discovery document

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-503, service-discovery, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm working with Google Cloud Endpoints, and I'm trying to generate a discovery document to create an iOS client library and so that I can test my endpoints. I tried to do it with this command, as said in the docs:

```
endpointscfg.py gen_discovery_doc -o . -f rpc appfile.ApiClass
```

With `appfile` and `ApiClass` changed to the real names.

When I run this, I get:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

Why is generating a discovery document accessing the internet at all? And why am I getting this error? And what can I do to fix it?

P.S. I already checked my code for basic errors like other types in message classes, bad hostnames, etc., but nothing there seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**RE: "Why is generating a discovery document accessing the internet at all?"**

Your API class is passed to the `ApiConfigGenerator.pretty_print_config_to_json` [method](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/endpoints/api_config.py?r=317#711) to create a descriptor that defines a bare API configuration. This descriptor is sent to a web API which hooks in to Google's API infrastructure to create a discovery document from the bare API configuration.

**RE: "And why am I getting this error?"**

Your API configuration is likely invalid, which is most often caused by an invalid API class definition. When you try to run or deploy the application, do you have any errors or stacktraces? If not, it's possible a bug in the code that runs the web service for generating discovery documents, and I'd be happy to look into it.

Comment: I've looked at the differences between my code and the tictactoe sample, and really can't find anything that might cause a problem. Would you look into it please?

Comment: I don't have anything to look into at the moment. Do you mind publishing your changes in the question? Which Tic-Tac-Toe sample are you using?

Comment: I should clarify -- I didn't change the sample directly, but rather wrote an API. Everything seems to be in order. I get post the code when I'm at my computer.

Answer (score 1):

After encountering a similar issue when generating the discovery document,

the 503 error will occur when something is not as is should be in my case it was an invalid API class definition.

Make sure that the @Api() definition starts with a lowercase character as it will return the 503 error otherwise.

For Example

```
//@Api(name = "thisMustBeLowerCase") otherwise client libraries wont compile.

 @Api(name = "sampleEndpoint") 
public class SampleEndpoint {...}
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: That's interesting. I'm no longer using endpoints, but this might have been the problem. Thanks.